# Cardano test node syncing is stucked on 99.27% (cardano node version 1.35.0 (latest) ,tried multiple times for syncing),any solution?

Tags: cardano

I tried multiple times for cardano-node syncing,but getting same problem again and again with cardano-node version 1.35.0, solution please...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which testnet are you using? The testnet mentioned here https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano is deprecated, a problem occurred when merging an update.
NetworkMagic: 1097911063

Try using on of the testnets written down in this documentation:
https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/getting-started
Just download all the files and run the node as usual.

***e.G. Preview Testnet:***
**Run the node:**

```
--config $HOME/cardano/preview/config.json \
--database-path $HOME/cardano/preview/db/ \
--socket-path $HOME/cardano/preview/db/node.socket \
--host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
--port 1337 \
--topology $HOME/cardano/preview/topology.json
```

**Sync the node**

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH="$HOME/cardano/preview/db/node.socket"
```

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 2
```